# Make widget as big as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

Here is some code I've written (and/or adapted from other sources):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QMainWindow,
                             QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, 
                             QDesktopWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class View(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(View, self).__init__()

        self.initScene()

    def initScene(self):     

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.canvas = Fig()
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.red))
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addWidget(self.canvas)

class Fig(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.factor = kwargs.pop("factor", 2)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, Figure(), *args,**kwargs)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        data = np.random.rand(1000)
        self.ax.plot(data, '-')


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        desktop = QDesktopWidget()
        rect = desktop.availableGeometry()
        self.setGeometry(rect.width()/10, rect.height()/10, rect.width()/1.2,
                   rect.height()/1.2)

        self.view = View()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

It produces the following window as its output:
[image]

I would like the plot in the middle to occupy as much space as possible, so that the red background becomes invisible.

This happens if I exclude the command setting the size of the window, that is indeed what happens. However, the window is then too small - I need to make it bigger.

I have tried using `self.view.setGeometry`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've had a look at the available modules in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html), but can't tell which might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to establish that the plot is shown covering all the available space within the window I see it unnecessary to use `QGraphicsView` since `Fig` is a `QWidget` that can be used directly in `setCentralWidget()`:

```
class Fig(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.factor = kwargs.pop("factor", 2)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, Figure(), *args,**kwargs)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        data = np.random.rand(1000)
        self.ax.plot(data, '-')


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        desktop = QDesktopWidget()
        rect = desktop.availableGeometry()
        self.setGeometry(rect.width()/10, rect.height()/10, rect.width()/1.2,
                   rect.height()/1.2)

        self.canvas = Fig()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### update: Using QScrollArea

```
class Fig(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.factor = kwargs.pop("factor", 2)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, Figure(), *args,**kwargs)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        data = np.random.rand(1000)
        self.ax.plot(data, '-')

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        FigureCanvas.showEvent(self, event)


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        desktop = QDesktopWidget()
        rect = desktop.availableGeometry()
        self.setGeometry(rect.width()/10, rect.height()/10, rect.width()/1.2,
                   rect.height()/1.2)

        self.canvas = Fig()
        self.canvas.draw()

        scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setCentralWidget(scrollArea)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yes, but the purpose of using QGraphicsView is that, when the window shrinks, it gives me scrollbars for free.

Comment: @Lupacante OKay, if you want use scrollbar I will update my solution. :D

Comment: @Lupacante check my answer

Comment: Perfect, I really appreciate you having helped me, thank you!